# SqlBulkCopy multiple tables in ASP.NET MVC unblockable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, sqlbulkcopy

I have to make a multiple copy of tables from one database to other with SqlBulkcopy from an ASP.NET MVC application.

The process takes more than 2 minutes, and I do not trust users.

Which is the best way to do the entire process, even if the user closes the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do such processes in an ASP.NET application. Read [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) to understand why. So do this task in a separate process than your application: a Windows service, a scheduled console application, ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have read It and looks like I am going to make it in a different way. Also I have found an answer made by you that matches to my actual question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637649/asp-net-mvc-background-threads-for-email-creation-and-sending/3637948#3637948