# Time consuming tasks on websites

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

My asp.net mvc 5 project and has a page where users submit a post and receive an email about the post they just made. how I can construct my program so the user will see a web page confirming the post has been made right away and the server then sends an email separately?

here's what I came up with:
use 2 controller actions. when the confirmation page loads it calls the send email action via javascript? is there a better solution?

also the email service may fail but that shouldn't affect the confirmation page

<del>UPDATE: the confirmation page should also notify the user when the email has been sent or failed</del>

UPDATE 2:
It should execute 1 and then return immediately. Status of 2 is not important
What's the syntax for async?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Confirm(string text)
{
    //1. Save post to database

    //2. Send email async

    return View();
}
```

Is this all I need if I don't care about delivery failures?

Comment: Why, I dare say this looks like a use case for `async`

Comment: If it shouldn't affect the confirmation page, why don't you make the email service asynchronous so your controller will return the view/result immediately after invoking the email service?

Comment: is async purely server-side? or does it require client-side library and browser support?

Comment: `async` is a delightful feature of C# 5, although you could certainly write asynchronous code before then. Hold on, I'll write an answer up

Comment: @James Actually given your edit - if you want to involve presentation, you'll need to use some client-side script, and aysnc may not be the best approach

Comment: The second requirement complicates things a little (as @NWard just mentioned). It's either going to require some client-side javascript magic (anything async such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) etc) or some clever [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) trickery.

Comment: i see. please ignore the second part then

Comment: Sending emails is pretty much instantaneous, why do you want to do it on a background process? Anyway, if you really want to, just fire-off another `Thread` or use a `ThreadPool`. Only make use of `async` features if you're interested in the return result of the background operation, which you don't want in ASP.NET because you'll want to return a response to the user as quickly as possible.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+[asp.net]++long+running - please make sure to read some and highlight how your post is different.

Comment: @alexeilevenkov i can't seem to find an example where it's a mvc controller using async.

Comment: I'm not sure how `async` applies to "return quickly before operation completed"... Generally "fire and forget" asynchronous operations (via `async` or threads/threadpool/`Task`s) is bad idea (i.e. you have no control on exceptions in such cases). Anyway following search http://www.bing.com/search?q=mvc+controller+using+async gives reasonable links for proper `async` actions (not going to help you with "long running operations")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to wait for database save and mail sending, you can create a task and return immediately:

```
public ActionResult PostData(string text)
{
    //1. Save post to database
    var databaseTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.SavePostToDatabase);

    //2. Send email async
    databaseTask.ContinueWith(task => this.SendEmail());

    //3. Confirmation view
    return RedirectToAction("PostConfirmed");
}

protected void SendEmail()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void SavePostToDatabase()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: do i need to add async in the signature? public async ActionResult PostData(string text)?

Comment: No since you want to return immediately, you do not want to await for the tasks to finish.

Comment: i see. so await makes it execute synchronously?

Comment: await makes it block until it's done, yes. But then if your blocked action is marked with async, other methods depending on it could still execute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: as an example: say the SendEmailAsync method returns a bool value in databaseTask.ContinueWith(task => this.SendEmailAsync()); how can i capture that value? so i can notify the client when email has been sent or failed

Comment: You could then make the client poll the server for the result. You could do that by sending the client a confirmation token. Then you capture the bool value returned by the SendEmailAsync by making it return a Task<bool>, then you once you get that value you put in the database or in the cache the response associated with the confirmation token.

Or you could make it a synchronous ajax request. Way simpler.

Comment: thanks. one more question regarding this. when saving to database when do you use SaveChanges() or SaveChangesAsync()? or are they the same? Task.Factory.StartNew(this.SaveChanges()) or Task.Factory.StartNew(this.SaveChangesAsync())

Comment: If you use a async you don't need the task as it is already asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is misleading since sending an email is not really a time consuming task unless you expect to send large attachments or do other processing in order to create the email content. In my experience on most servers one email is sent in milliseconds.

For your example there is no need to add two controllers actions nor is asynch a requirement.

What you want can be done by just creating a regular action like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostMessage(string messageText)
    {
        string result;

        try
        {
            // mail.Send() here
            // can use SendAsync but then need to handle result feedback via JavaScript
            result = "Email was sent";
        }
        catch
        {
            result = "Sending Email Failed";
        }

        return View("PostConfirmation", result);
    }
```

EDIT:
If you have unreliable network I would just send email asynchronous and show "email queued" on your confirmation screen.

If you want to stay away from JavaScript polling then just store messages from background tasks at the begin of your action through something like: ViewBag.AsynchMessage = "Your Post was sent via email" with the result. Just include the ViewBag in your main Layout in a suitable location and your users can see messages as you process them. don't forget to empty the ViewBag on subsequent requests to keep UI clean.

Comment: network connection may fail thus taking a long time

Comment: @James why would it take long if the network connection failed, did you change the time outs to something else?

Comment: all default value. ~30 seconds is long in this case. i want to present a page immediately. email delivery can fail silently

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SmtpClient.SendAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx) to send your message directly from the controller asynchronously, assuming you're relying on `System.Net.Mail` as a provider and not an outside extension.

Example syntax in controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostData(object data)
    {
        //1. Save your post data here...

        MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
        //2. Play with your message object here...

        SmtpClient myClient = new SmtpClient("your.smtp.com", 587);
        myClient.SendAsync(myMessage, "myToken");

        return View();
    }
```

You'll have to handle return values in the view with Javascript, if you care about those later on.

I have to agree with @HighCs though - a confirmation email, even an HTML message with a little data thrown in, shouldn't take so long to send that you need to worry about asynchronous actions. You could include your original request of confirming the mail sent by doing the following instead:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostData(object data)
    {
        //...Save your post data here...

        MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
        //...Play with your message object here...

        SmtpClient myClient = new SmtpClient("your.smtp.com", 587);

        bool sentOk = true;
        try
        {
            myClient.Send(myMessage);
        }
        catch
        {
            sentOk = false;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("PostConfirmed", new { confirmEmail = sentOk });
    }
```

You can do whatever you'd like to generate the "PostConfirmed" view, and you can use that `confirmEmail` boolean to adjust the view's content depending on an e-mail error.

There's some more in-depth info regarding `async` requests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129933/sendmailasync-use-in-mvc), too.

**EDIT:** Per your comment to @HighCs about connection failure, consider implementing this in your `SmtpClient` config: [SmtpClient.Timeout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx)