# Running a background task for sending emails when a user posts to a discussion board in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient, hangfire

I need to send emails via SMTP to all subscribers of a discussion board. If there a lot (say 1000+) subscribers, I do not want the users who posts a new post to have to wait while the notification emails are being sent out.

At first I thought I could use: `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`

But, as [this post explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129933/sendmailasync-use-in-mvc), *"Async is not a magic wand that makes the action return the response quicker. Your task (in this case, sending an email) takes as long as it takes and async or not, the action will not return a response until the task has completed."* Async is more about being efficient with threads than it is about making a task run faster.

First, is my research about SendMailAsync correct? I don't think it is a correct solution.

Second, what would be a way to achieve my goal? A **background task**?
I've heard of [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/). Is something like Hangfire what I need to use? Or could I just use **an AJAX call** to send the emails?

Btw, I'm using ASP.NET Core and .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: What requires you to trigger the emails from the web application to begin with?  You could write a separate program, e.g. a Windows service, that does this.

Comment: I don't have to use the web application to send the emails. Just trying to weigh all my options. So I guess I could use a Windows service. Thanks for the suggestion @JohnWu

Comment: Yes, Hangfire can work in this scenario. The nice thing about it is that it's embedded in your application, with no need for a separate program. There other other programs out there too. Scott Hanselman has the [definitive blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) on this in my opinion.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation about hangfire. would it be possible to just use an AJAX call though? @mason

Comment: AJAX calls are subject to the same request/response lifecycle as regular webpages.

Comment: but let's say the user creates a discussion post, and then I make an ajax call to send emails to all subscribers. even if the user navigates away, as long as the ajax request gets to the server, the call will run. right? @mason

Comment: Probably - but what if an error is encountered while sending emails? Or the appdomain is recycled when only half of the emails have been sent out? What if you want to check the status of the background jobs? I get that you want to limit system complexity, but these are important things to consider as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a message queue service (e.g. RabbitMQ or AWS SQS) running on a separate server?  then post a message to that server with details of what needs to be done (in this case what to send to whom), and then the message service can pull messages off the queue at its leisure, process them (send out 1000s of emails) and then get the next thing off the queue.

Comment: I don't want to go with a multi-server solution, just yet, but I'll keep RabbitMQ in mind (although I don't think it has support for .NET Core yet).
@Neil

Answer (score 0):

I used hangfire in a similar situation. Here's how I implemented it.

1. Stored the list of emails to be sent in the database.
2. Used hangfire to process the emails in the background.

You could use a separate queue/server for the processing. Did the job for me.

Check this post on  [Background Processing in ASP.net using Hangfire](https://www.evertechie.com/hangfire-background-task-processing-asp-net/)

Also, go through the [hangfire best practices](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/best-practices.html) before implementing.